# carousel in modal window using bootstrap and angularUi

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create an image gallery using angular ui and bootstrap. The image gallery has 4x4 rows of photos and I want the user to be able to open the photo in a modal window when he clicks on the photo. The modal window should display the photo in a carousal so he can see the entire image gallery by "next" and "prev"

Below is my code. The modal window opens up but does not contain the carousel.

### HTML code

```
    <div id="listing-detail-gallery" class="container">
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" ng-repeat="image in         selectedListing.images">
          <img class="img-responsive" ng-click="openModal()"       src="assets/images/{{image}}"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

### Controller

```
    controller( 'ListingDetailsCtrl', function ListingDetailsCtrl($scope ,$modal, $stateParams,ListingService,CategoryService) {
       $scope.id= $stateParams.id;
        $scope.selectedListing = ListingService.find($scope.id);
        $scope.category= CategoryService.findByCode($scope.selectedListing.category);


        //Open Modal Window for image
        $scope.openModal = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          animation: true,
          size:"lg",
          template: '<div class="modal-body"><carousel><slide ng-repeat="image in items">{{image}}        <img style="margin:auto;" ng-src="assets/images/{{image}}"></slide></carousel></div>',
          resolve: {
            items: function () {
              return $scope.selectedListing.images;
            }
          }
        });

      };
```

please help me if you can figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: Did this work for you or did you decide to integrate that lightbox plugin?

Comment: i decided to use your solution. it works well except for the "active" part. Some times the carousal doesn;t display the image selected. when i close the carousal and select the image the second time, it works.

Comment: Hmmm, wonder what could be causing that.  Any errors?

Comment: no errors. In fact, the active flag is set and the image src is correct. looking into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demo (It's based off on an older demo I had so it has a slightly different template and some CSS added to make it pretty, but it's the same code described below):

## [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/joM8aUiWzgaHecolZFAV?p=preview)

I would refactor your controller so that you don't have to use a separate controller for your modalInstance.  That will make it much easier:

```
controller( 'ListingDetailsCtrl', function ListingDetailsCtrl($scope, $modal, $stateParams,ListingService,CategoryService) {
  $scope.id= $stateParams.id;
  $scope.selectedListing = ListingService.find($scope.id);
  $scope.category= CategoryService.findByCode($scope.selectedListing.category);
  $scope.openModal = function(indx) {
    //This will let you open the carousel to the image that was clicked
    $scope.selectedListing.images[indx].active=true;

    $scope.modalInstance= $modal.open({
      animation: true,
      size:"lg",
      //To set the active slide when loading the carousel, just add
      //active = "image.active" to the slide element. Also, we're using 
      //the current scope, so change your slide repeat to "image in
      //selectedListing.images" 
      template: '<div class="modal-body"><carousel><slide ng-repeat="image in selectedListing.images" active="image.active">{{image}}<img style="margin:auto;" ng-src="assets/images/{{image}}"></slide></carousel></div>',
    });
  };
  $scope.ok = function () {
    $scope.modalInstance.close();
  };
});
```

Then you just need to make one change to your HTML view so that you are passing the index of the image to the openModal fn:

```
<div id="listing-detail-gallery" class="container">
  <ul class="row">
    <li class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" ng-repeat="image in selectedListing.images">
      <img class="img-responsive" ng-click="openModal($index)" src="assets/images/{{image}}"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

P.S. You'll notice that I hid the carousel indicators in the carousel.  There's a really ugly unresolved [bug](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3764) in ui-bootstrap 0.13.0 that causes the indicators to be ordered incorrectly if you have a lot of slides.  There are two simple options to fix this if you want to use the indicators.  One is modify the carousel.html template and remove `orderBy:'index'` from the indicators. Or, two use the 0.12.x version until fixed. (I'd go for the former).

Comment: Hi @jme11. I have used that plunker. I have found one issue i.e. when I click on the first image & then move slider one by one to see the other images & then close the slider then again click on the first image, I got the last opened image on the slider. Index is passing correct but as per index image is not displaying. Could you please help me to sort out. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I have found one thing that class `active` is saved in the last image div that's why when I'll click on any previous image it display the last image which was opened earlier. Please help me to sort out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reinvent the wheel (although it can be a good learning experience sometimes) I would suggest you use an existing angular module. I recently used this one in a project and it contains all the features that you're looking for: [angular bootstrap lightbox](https://github.com/compact/angular-bootstrap-lightbox). The basic example will get you up and running with the functionality you're after.

```
<ul ng-controller="GalleryCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="image in images">
        <a ng-click="openLightboxModal($index)">
           <img ng-src="{{image.thumbUrl}}" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

angular.module('app').controller('GalleryCtrl', function ($scope, Lightbox) {
  $scope.images = [
    {
      'url': '1.jpg',
      'caption': 'Optional caption',
      'thumbUrl': 'thumb1.jpg' // used only for this example
    },
    {
      'url': '2.gif',
      'thumbUrl': 'thumb2.jpg'
    },
    {
      'url': '3.png',
      'thumbUrl': 'thumb3.png'
    }
  ];

  $scope.openLightboxModal = function (index) {
    Lightbox.openModal($scope.images, index);
  };
});
```